# Apache reverse proxy setup (for node.js application) not working?

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

### What I am trying to do

After running the command `(export PORT=3000 && node server.js)` my node.js app ([StackEdit](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit)) is served at: `http://example.com:3000/`.

The command `(export PORT=80 && node server.js)` wouldn't work considering that Apache already uses port 80 on the server.

As I am new to Node.js, an easy way to make the node.js app available at `http://example.com/` (i.e. port 80) would be to set up Apache as a reverse proxy.

### Here's what I've tried

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

**Trial (1):**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/editor.aahanblog.com/logs/access.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://example.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This simply shows the directory listing for the `public` directory. So, in this case the requests aren't reaching the node.js app.

**Trial (2):**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /var/www/example.com/public>
        ProxyPass http://mydomain:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://mydomain:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work either. It takes me to some default apache page.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Location directive as

```
<Location /> from <Location /var/www/example.com/public>
```

basically, Location directive is a prefix of the path component of the URL